# E-mail saindo com caracteres estranhos no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, envio-de-email

Galera, uso um sistema PHP + MySQL, porém todo e-mail que busca os dados do e-mail no banco de dados como assunto, etc..., nas palavras aonde tem acentos sai tudo errado, um exemplo: não fica tipo isso N$$O$, já mudei o padrão do banco para UTF-8 porém não resolveu.

Answer (score 3):

Vc definiu os headers do email?

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from.">\r\n";
mail($to, $subj, chunk_split(base64_encode($msg)), $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a classe PHPMailer para realizar o envio de e-mails, na página no Github há um bom exemplo de uso:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Por padrão o PHPMailer vem configurado com charset ISO-8859-1, aconselho deixar como está e testar, se os caracteres acentuados continuarem apresentando problema, então você pode alterar para UTF-8:

```
$mail->Charset = 'UTF-8';
```

A documentação completa está em http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter os valores para UTF8 em tempo real usando as funções do PHP, [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) e utf8_decode:

```
utf8_encode($campoDoBanco)
```

Ou converter de UTF8 para ISO usando:

```
utf8_decode ($campoDoBanco)
```

Isso resolve no caso do e-mail, assim não precisa mexer no resto da aplicação. Lembrando que para o e-mail ficar certinho, é recomendado você não utilizar ENCODING algum, e sim apenas converter para HTML usando o [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php):

```
htmlentities ($campoDoBanco, ENT_QUOTES, ENCODING_DO_BANCO);
```

Normalmente, o padrão do ENCODING_DO_BANCO é 'ISO-8859-1' (latin1), mas você pode trocar para 'UTF-8'. Para verificar o encoding do banco, execute:

```
$link    = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);

echo "O conjunto de caracteres atual é: $charset\n";
```

Comment: Justo o contrário, é fundamental usar o encoding e o header correto. Esse "é recomendado você não utilizar ENCODING algum" é uma péssima idéia. Entendo que se usar o entities, o encoding é irrelevante, mas aí tem que avisar o usuário que o set de caracteres é mais limitado (nem tudo tem uma entidade "por extenso"). Outra coisa: "por padrão o encoding do banco" é ISO, não é bem assim. Melhor verificar no servidor, tem versões recentes vindo com UTF-8, e tem host que já configura UTF-8 como padrão.

Comment: Lembre que Roberto que enviar e-mails... e muitos clientes de e-mail não aceitam ENCODING direito... principalmente os da M$! de qualquer forma, estou editando para melhorar a resposta.